# How can I print a whole DOM element using angular-screenshot?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, screenshot, angularjs-3rd-party

I already tried to copy/paste the example code on the webpage: https://weihanchen.github.io/angular-screenshot/
The thing is they are using a whole controller for it, and I have my controllers separated by views. This is how I add them to my "main" js:

```
    .state("main.pallet", {
        url: "/palletize",
        templateUrl: "app/views/pallet.html",
        data: {pageTitle: 'Entarimado.'},
        controller: "Pallet",
        resolve: {
            deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', function($ocLazyLoad) {
                return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                    name: 'TepaPrime',
                    insertBefore: '#ng_load_plugins_before', // load the above css files before '#ng_load_plugins_before'
                    files: [
                        'app/js/filters/filters.js',
                        'app/js/directives/numericFormat.js',
                        'app/js/directives/trimText.js',
                        'app/js/directives/nextOnEnter.js',
                        'app/js/factories/crud.factory.js',
                        'app/js/controllers/modals/palletContent.js',
                        'app/js/controllers/pallet.js',
                        'app/js/services/printDocument.js'
                    ]                    
                });
            }]
        }
    })
```

This is my printDocument.js where I pasted the code from the example (and modified it to get it to work):

```
'use strict';
function appController($scope) {
  var self = this;
  self.fullScreenApi;
  self.downloadFull = downloadFull;
  this.downloadFull = function() {
      if (self.fullScreenApi) self.fullScreenApi.downloadFull();
   }
   return downloadFull;
}
angular
    .module('TepaPrime')
    .service('printDocument', appController);
```

Then I inject it in my view's controller by doing this:

```
function Pallet($rootScope, $scope, $state, $timeout, $uibModal, $http, $filter, crud, sessionService, printDocument) {
  ...
}
```

The problem is it doesn't work and it crashes the whole page and throws this error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/unpr?p0=copeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%20printDocument

I'd really appretiate some help, as I've been stuck with this for a long time now and don't seem able to get closer to a solution.

Comment: Add angular-screenshot dependency to module: `angular.module("TepaPrime", ["angular-screenshot"])`

Comment: Already tried, but it doesn't work. It won't show the error anymore, but the page stays in blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a quite long struggle, I was able to fix it by changing the html from

```
      <button class="btn btn-info" ng-if="appCtrl.isFullOpen" ng-click="appCtrl.downloadFull()">
        <i class="material-icons">Descargar tabla</i>
      </button>
```

To:

```
      <button class="btn btn-info" ng-if="appCtrl.isFullOpen" ng-click="appCtrl.fullScreenApi.downloadFull()">
        <i class="material-icons">Descargar tabla</i>
      </button>
```

The problem is that the downloadFull() function was inside fullscreenApi.